# Como retornar o foco em um EditText depois de um notifyDataSetChanged() no recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-adapter

O problema é com notifyDataSetChanged() quando atualizo o recyclerview o EditText perde o foco queria que ele não perdesse o foco, já tentei com requestfocos não dá.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode guardar um id do edit que está com foco e depois se ele for renderizado novamente você seta o foco. Mas para esse problema você pode resolver de várias maneiras. Segue um link com uma delas

https://radhedubey.wordpress.com/2014/08/24/android-listview-with-edittext-loses-focus-when-the-keyboard-displays/

Comment: Tiago, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Agradecemos que queira ajudar! No entanto tenha em conta que o link que colocou neste momento é válido mas nada nos garante que continue a sê-lo no futuro. O stackoverflow deve ser encarado como um repositório de conhecimento. Ao responder devemos pensar, não só em quem perguntou, mas também em todos aqueles que no futuro poderão usufruir da nossa resposta.